# Jquery and Checking Attributes Value

Tags: jquery

If have an element that maybe disabled on a page, and would like to check it's value before I do something.

How is this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ? Be more clear what kind of an element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML looks something like this:

```
<input id="my_input_field" value="my value" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Then you can use the following jQuery to retrieve the value:

```
$("#my_input_field").val();
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) to find out in what way you can access elements in the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of jQuery

[Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) -> Select the right element
[Attributes](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes) -> Check what the value is

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#input_field").attr("disabled");
```

to see if the input_field is disabled